# Why can't a const T*& bind to a T*?

Tags: c++

VS2010 shows error C2440: `'return' : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'const char *&` in `f3` below. Why is it not possible to return a `char*` when the return type is `const char*&`?

```
const char* const& f1()
{
    static char* x = new char[5]();
    return x;
}

char* const& f2()
{
    static char* x = new char[5]();
    return x;
}

const char* & f3()
{
    static char* x = new char[5]();
    return x;    // error C2440
}

char* & f4()
{
    static char* x = new char[5]();
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Paragraph 8.5.3/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after initialization. Note that initialization of a
> reference is treated very differently from assignment to it. Argument passing (5.2.2) and **function value
> return (6.6.3) are initializations**.

This basically tells you that returning a value from a function is equivalent to performing an initialization. Therefore, function `f3()` doesn't compile for the same reason the last initialization in the code snippet below doesn't compile:

```
char c = 'a';
char* x = &c;
const char*& y = x; // ERROR!
```

The type of the object referenced by `y` is `const char*`, while the type of the expression we are trying to initialize it with (i.e. the type of `x`) is `char*`. Those are *different types*, and when binding a reference the types of the initializer expression and of the object referenced by the initialized reference **must be identical** (with an exception for base and derived classes, which are not involved here), **apart from *top-level* cv qualifications**.

Here, the `const` qualification in `const char*` is *not* a top-level qualification, because it applies to the pointed object, and not to the pointer itself: while the pointed `char` value cannot be modified through a `const char*` pointer, the pointer itself *can* be reassigned.

In Standard terms, this means that the types `const char*` and `char*` are not *reference-related*:

> Given types “`cv1 T1`” and “`cv2 T2`,” “`cv1 T1`” is *reference-related* to “`cv2 T2`” if `T1` is the **same type as** `T2`, or `T1` is a base class of `T2`. “cv1 T1” is *reference-compatible* with “`cv2 T2`” if `T1` is *reference-related* to `T2` and `cv1` is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, `cv2`. [...]

On the other hand, function `f2()` compiles, consistently with the fact that the initialization in the last line below is legal:

```
char c = 'a';
char* x = &c;
char* const& y = x; // OK
```

Here, the type of the referenced object is `char* const`, which (unlike `const char*`) is reference-compatible with `char*` in the sense defined by the Paragraph quoted above *(the `const` qualification is a **top-level** qualification in this case).

In Particular, per 8.5.3/5:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> — If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression
>
> - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), **and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2,”** or
>
> [...]

The omitted part is not relevant to this case. Here, `char* const` and `char*` are *reference-compatible*, and the initialization is legal (and `f2()` compiles). On the other hand, `const char*` and `char*` are **not** *reference-compatible*, and the initialization is illegal (and `f3()` does not compile).

Comment: What is a "top level" cv- qualification? How do you characterize the term "top level" in this context?

Comment: @user1042389: I'll try with an example: in `int const` and `int* const`, `const` is top-level; in `int const*` (which is the same as `const int*`), `const` is not top-level, because it applies to the pointed `int`, not to the pointer itself. In general, in C++ you can build compound types by constructs such as "pointer to", "reference to", "array of", etc. When you compose type this way (e.g. "reference to pointer to pointer of `char`") your type has a hierarchical structure (a chain, in our case). A top-level qualifier is a qualifier that applies to the top node of this structure

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason you can't cast from `char **` to `const char **`. Otherwise you could write

```
f3() = "hello";
```

and a subsequent call to f3 would be able to write to the memory of the string literal, aliased to the static local `x`.

Comment: Hmm, and why f3() = "hello"; compile? f3() is const, or? It count like in the declaration of i in const int& i =b;?

Comment: `f3() = "hello"` compiles because your particular compiler is letting you do something dumb for legacy reasons.  Many C APIs had `char*` interfaces that they would promise not to write to.  So by letting string literals be turned into `char*`s silently, the C API still works.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
void problem( const char*& output, const char* input )
{
  output = input; // legal, const char*& = const char*
}

int main() {
  const char buff[] = "hello";
  char* out = nullptr;
  problem( const_cast<const char*&>(out), &buff[0] );
  out[0] = 'H'; // I just changed a const array's first character
  std::cout << &buff[0] << "\n";
}
```

This prints "Hello", which is evidence I just engaged in undefined behavior.  To do so, I had to use a `const_cast`.  If you could initialize a `const char*&` with a `char*`, I wouldn't have to do the `const_cast` to invoke the undefined behavior.

"But" one might say "this doesn't match the exact case that the OP posted!"

Which is true.

```
// the "legal" way to do what the OP wants to do, but it leads to undefined
// behavior:
const char*& problem2( char*& c ) { return const_cast<const char*&>(c); }
void problem3( const char*& left, const char* right ) { left = right; }

#include <iostream>
int main() {
  char* c = nullptr;
  char const* buff = "hello undefined behavior";
  problem3( problem2(c), buff );
  c[0] = 'H';
  std::cout << buff << "\n";
}
```

also prints "Hello undefined behavior".

"But", one might say, "you turned a `char*&` into a `const char*&`, not a `char*` into a `const char*&`.

Very well:

```
void problem3( const char*& left, const char* right ) { left = right; }
const char*& problem4( char x = 0 ) {
  static char* bob = nullptr;
  if (bob && x)
    bob[0] = x;
  return const_cast<const char*&>(bob);
}
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  char const* buff = "hello problem";
  problem3( problem4(), buff );
  problem4('H');
  std::cout << buff << "\n";
}
```

Again, that incriminating capital `H` (well, actually, undefined behavior that typically is a capital `H`).